Understanding the output of Google's wide and deep model?
I'm trying to implement Google's wide and deep model and I have a question about its output.
According to the equation (3) in the paper:
$$ P(Y=1|X) = \sigma(w_{wide}^T[x,\phi(x)] + w_{deep}^T a^{(l_f)+b} $$
Is $P(Y=1|X)$ supposed to be a scalar? I expected this, but when I lookeat at a kaggle notebook the final layer (referred to as head) outputs a vector with size equal to the cross-product of the features.
self.head = nn.Sequential(
  nn.Linear(embed_dict_len + 256, embed_dict_len),
)

In my train data (subset of movielens 100k)  there are 944 users and 1683 items, which means that the cross-product would make a matrix with 1.5M values. In this part I could just use a sparse matrix, but what about the parameters of the model?
If $P(Y=1|X)$ is a vector of size 1.5M, as in that notebook, then $w_{wide}$ should have a size of $1.5M^2$ = 2 trillion values or 10 TB! Just in the wide part!!
On the other hand, if $P(Y=1|X)$ is a scalar, how I'm I supposed to make the recommendations? Do I have to make the forward pass for every possible user-item combination?
Perhaps the output size is the number of movies, and then I just have to make the forward pass for each user.


Is P(Y=1|X) supposed to be a scalar?
...outputs a vector with size equal to the cross-product of the features.

No. Since the goal stated in the notebook is to predict which movie the user will watch next, the output vector is defined by the number of unique movies items['movie id'].nunique() + 1 (1683). This is compared to the vector representing which movie was actually watched next, with the loss calculated via CrossEntropyLoss.

I could just use a sparse matrix, but what about the parameters of the model?

Per the answers to the question you linked:

Indeed you will have a large and very sparse matrix.


Since your dataset is a mix between dense features (continuous features) and sparse (cross) you can separate your network in two: the sparse will be directly sent to your output and thus treated as they would be in a linear model while your dense features will go through several hidden layers before going to the output.

This is why the model has a wide (sparse) and a deep (dense) part.

Neural networks perform well with dense, correlated features while linear models work better with sparse and low correlated features.

Printing the actual "head" parameter sizes:

It's only ~3 million in its single Linear layer.
Hope this helps clarify the model structure.
Edit, since this is a bit long for a comment response:
In the paper:

The retrieval system returns a short list of items that best match the query ... the ranking system ranks all items by their scores. The scores are usually P(y|x), the probability of a user action label y given the features x ...


In this paper, we focus on the ranking model using the Wide & Deep learning framework.

So after retrieving a short list of relevant items to score (a vector), the model generates a vector of predicted rankings for those items. The rankings can be compared to actual user interactions, and a loss calculated.

The wide component and deep component are combined ... which is then fed to one common logistic loss function for joint training.

Here, "logistic loss function", indicates Cross-Entropy loss like the kaggle notebook implementation.
For the Microsoft Recommender example (assuming this one) they only want to predict a scalar value (the movie rating) and appear to use Mean Squared Error as their loss function.
The top-K recommendations part just applies the already trained model.

My question then is, what did the original paper do? Does it return a scalar? Or a vector? The Microsoft Recommenders library has a wide and deep model that outputs a single scalar, and then tests with all possible user-item pairs to get the top k recommendations.
